# Can WPF listbox get around another component?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I need to have fixed on the right on the window a textblock where I set Note, the rest of the window could be a listbox filled of selectable items. My problem is that Note can be visible or not and the selectable items should be wrapped all around like in Word with image and Wrap Text set to "Square"

Examples:

[image: Note with one selectable item]
[image: Note with multiple selectable items]

**ADDED**

I created a custom UniformGrid, I added a property NoteRowToSkip that rapresent the rows to skip in the last column on the left. I override ArrangeOverride and added the the skip behavior that I want.
Debugging seems that values are correct, but has the same behavior of UniformGrid.

```
    public class UniformNoteWrapGrid : Panel
    {
        private int m_Rows;
        private int m_Columns;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NoteRowToSkipProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(NoteRowToSkip), typeof(int), typeof(UniformGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure), ValidateNoteRowToSkip);
        private static bool ValidateNoteRowToSkip(object o)
        {
            return (int)o >= 0;
        }
        public int Columns
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Columns",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(UniformGrid),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
                ValidateColumns);

        private static bool ValidateColumns(object o)
        {
            return (int)o >= 0;
        }

        public int Rows
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(RowsProperty);
            set => SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int),
                typeof(UniformGrid),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
                ValidateRows);

        private static bool ValidateRows(object o)
        {
            return (int)o >= 0;
        }

        public int NoteRowToSkip
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(NoteRowToSkipProperty);
            set => SetValue(NoteRowToSkipProperty, value);
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            UpdateComputedValues();

            var childConstraint = new Size(constraint.Width / m_Columns, constraint.Height / m_Rows);
            double maxChildDesiredWidth = 0.0;
            double maxChildDesiredHeight = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
            {
                var child = InternalChildren[i];

                child.Measure(childConstraint);
                var childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;

                if (maxChildDesiredWidth < childDesiredSize.Width)
                    maxChildDesiredWidth = childDesiredSize.Width;

                if (maxChildDesiredHeight < childDesiredSize.Height)
                    maxChildDesiredHeight = childDesiredSize.Height;
            }

            return new Size(maxChildDesiredWidth * m_Columns, maxChildDesiredHeight * m_Rows);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            var childBounds = new Rect(0, 0, arrangeSize.Width / m_Columns, arrangeSize.Height / m_Rows);
            double xStep = childBounds.Width;
            double xBound = arrangeSize.Width - 1.0;
            var row = 1;
            var column = 1;

            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                child.Arrange(childBounds);

                if (child.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                    continue;

                childBounds.X += xStep;
                column++;
                var testXBound = xBound;
                if (IsCellForNote(row, column))
                    testXBound -= childBounds.Height;

                if (!(childBounds.X >= testXBound))
                    continue;

                childBounds.Y += childBounds.Height;
                childBounds.X = 0;
                row++;
                column = 1;
            }

            return arrangeSize;
        }

        private bool IsCellForNote(int row, int column)
        {
            if (row > NoteRowToSkip)
                return true;

            return column != Columns;
        }

        private void UpdateComputedValues()
        {
            m_Columns = Columns;
            m_Rows = Rows;

            //if (FirstColumn >= m_Columns)
            //  FirstColumn = 0;

            if (m_Rows != 0 && m_Columns != 0)
                return;

            int nonCollapsedCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
            {
                var child = InternalChildren[i];
                if (child.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
                    nonCollapsedCount++;
            }

            if (nonCollapsedCount == 0)
                nonCollapsedCount = 1;

            if (m_Rows == 0)
            {
                if (m_Columns > 0)
                    m_Rows = (nonCollapsedCount + (m_Columns - 1)) / m_Columns;
                else
                {
                    m_Rows = (int)Math.Sqrt(nonCollapsedCount);
                    if ((m_Rows * m_Rows) < nonCollapsedCount)
                        m_Rows++;

                    m_Columns = m_Rows;
                }
            }
            else if (m_Columns == 0)
                m_Columns = (nonCollapsedCount + (m_Rows - 1)) / m_Rows;
        }
    }
```

Any idea in what's not working in my code?

**SOLVED**

Was a problem with if conditions.
The working version is below.

```
    public class UniformNoteWrapGrid : Panel
    {
        private int m_Rows;
        private int m_Columns;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NoteRowToSkipProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(NoteRowToSkip), typeof(int), typeof(UniformGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure), ValidateNoteRowToSkip);
        private static bool ValidateNoteRowToSkip(object o)
        {
            return (int)o >= 0;
        }

        public int Columns
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Columns",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(UniformGrid),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
                ValidateColumns);

        private static bool ValidateColumns(object o)
        {
            return (int)o >= 0;
        }

        public int Rows
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(RowsProperty);
            set => SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int),
                typeof(UniformGrid),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
                ValidateRows);

        private static bool ValidateRows(object o)
        {
            return (int)o >= 0;
        }

        public int NoteRowToSkip
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(NoteRowToSkipProperty);
            set => SetValue(NoteRowToSkipProperty, value);
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            UpdateComputedValues();

            var childConstraint = new Size(constraint.Width / m_Columns, constraint.Height / m_Rows);
            double maxChildDesiredWidth = 0.0;
            double maxChildDesiredHeight = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
            {
                var child = InternalChildren[i];

                child.Measure(childConstraint);
                var childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;

                if (maxChildDesiredWidth < childDesiredSize.Width)
                    maxChildDesiredWidth = childDesiredSize.Width;

                if (maxChildDesiredHeight < childDesiredSize.Height)
                    maxChildDesiredHeight = childDesiredSize.Height;
            }

            return new Size(maxChildDesiredWidth * m_Columns, maxChildDesiredHeight * m_Rows);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
        {
            var childBounds = new Rect(0, 0, arrangeSize.Width / m_Columns, arrangeSize.Height / m_Rows);
            double xStep = childBounds.Width;
            double xBound = arrangeSize.Width - 1.0;
            var row = 1;
            var column = 1;

            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                child.Arrange(childBounds);

                if (child.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                    continue;

                childBounds.X += xStep;
                column++;
                var testXBound = xBound;
                if (IsCellForNote(row, column))
                    testXBound -= xStep;

                if (!(childBounds.X >= testXBound))
                    continue;

                childBounds.Y += childBounds.Height;
                childBounds.X = 0;
                row++;
                column = 1;
            }

            return arrangeSize;
        }

        private bool IsCellForNote(int row, int column)
        {
            if (row > NoteRowToSkip)
                return false;

            return column == Columns;
        }

        private void UpdateComputedValues()
        {
            m_Columns = Columns;
            m_Rows = Rows;

            //if (FirstColumn >= m_Columns)
            //  FirstColumn = 0;

            if (m_Rows != 0 && m_Columns != 0)
                return;

            int nonCollapsedCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
            {
                var child = InternalChildren[i];
                if (child.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
                    nonCollapsedCount++;
            }

            if (nonCollapsedCount == 0)
                nonCollapsedCount = 1;

            if (m_Rows == 0)
            {
                if (m_Columns > 0)
                    m_Rows = (nonCollapsedCount + (m_Columns - 1)) / m_Columns;
                else
                {
                    m_Rows = (int)Math.Sqrt(nonCollapsedCount);
                    if ((m_Rows * m_Rows) < nonCollapsedCount)
                        m_Rows++;

                    m_Columns = m_Rows;
                }
            }
            else if (m_Columns == 0)
                m_Columns = (nonCollapsedCount + (m_Rows - 1)) / m_Rows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would still need a custom Panel for such a layout.

Answer (score 0):

`WrapPanel` with a bit of tuning could help you to achieve something like this:

[image]

Here I used `ItemsControl` as a host for items with `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="panel">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NoteItem}">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="50" Height="150" Margin="10" 
                           Text="{Binding Text}" Background="LightBlue">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visible}" Value="False" >
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ListItem}">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Text}" Background="LightGray"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And to try it put that in code behind:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class NoteItem:Item
{
    public bool Visible{ get; set; }
}

public class ListItem : Item
{
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    ObservableCollection<Item> list = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NoteItem note = new NoteItem { Text = "This is a note", Visible = true };
        list.Add(note);
        for(int i=0;i<20; i++)
            list.Add(new ListItem { Text = "This is a list item" });
        panel.ItemsSource = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not good for me, because Note needs to be on the right and could take two position like the second image that I posted